# What does the * in *len() do?

Tags: python

In the following code, why is there an asterisk in front of len()?

```
def censor (text,word):
  if word in text:
    text= text.replace(word, "*" *len(word))
  return text
```

Why can't you just put len(word)?

Comment: Your code would be easier to understand and the purpose of the asterisk would be more obvious if you left some space after the *: `"*" * len(word)`.

Comment: `"z" * 5` is `"zzzzz"`.  So it follows that  `"*" * len(word)` is `"**********"`  (assuming the length of the word is ten characters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is a bit misleading, it should read:

```
text = text.replace(word, "*" * len(word))
```

The asterisk is the multiplication operator - it's multiplying the string `"*"` by the length of the word you're censoring to build up the censored string.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> word = "hello"
>>> len(word)
5
>>> "*" * len(word)
'*****'
```

> Why can't you just put len(word)?

`len(word)` gets you `5`.

Then we multiply `'*'` by `5` and we get `'*****'`

Answer (score 0):

What the code does is it multiplies the asterisk by the length of the word. The `*` is a multiplication operator. You can't not put the `len` because then the code would error (`"*"len(word)` is invalid syntax). For example, if there were five characters, it would put five asterisks.

```
len("qwert") * "*" = "*****"
```